# PHP Mysql Select query with BETWEEN

Tags: php, mysql, between

I am trying to use two query using between but when I add the between code it does not work.  This is the code that is working for me before using BETWEEN.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name , liking , id , address , description FROM locations WHERE liking LIKE '%{$likeArray[$newCount]}%'");
```

This is the code with BETWEEN that is not working.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name , liking , id , address , description FROM locations WHERE ‘long’ BETWEEN ‘$Slong’ AND ‘$Blong’ AND lat BETWEEN ‘$Slat’ AND ‘$Blat’ AND liking LIKE '%{$likeArray[$newCount]}%'");
```

Comment: You need to use parenthesis to wrap your logic

Comment: @SaadSuri Do you mean like parenthesis around the two BETWEEN statements?

Comment: Yes you need to evaluate them like your desired result. SELECT name , liking , id , address , description FROM locations WHERE (‘long’ BETWEEN ‘$Slong’ AND ‘$Blong’) AND (lat BETWEEN ‘$Slat’ AND ‘$Blat’) AND liking LIKE '%{$likeArray[$newCount]}%'

Comment: Learn how to use parameters. Don't put values into quests strings, it's dangerous. Also `mysql_` functions have been deprecated a long time ago, switch to mysqli or PDO

Comment: And yes @SamiKuhmonen is right you need to use mysqli or pdo. mysql_ is deprecated and do this with a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here.

First, I will say, do not use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated in 5.5+ and removed in 7.0. Your alternatives are mysqli_* functions, or to use PDO. I prefer PDO, but I can see why using mysqli_* would be handy, as you could do a text search for `mysql_` and replace with `mysqli_`.

Now, on to your problem. You are using back- and forward-ticks for everything, where you should use back-ticks and single quote marks. Column names should be enclosed in backticks (`) and text should be encolsed in single quotation marks ('), like below:

```
$result = mysqli_query(
    "SELECT name , liking , id , address , description FROM locations WHERE `long` BETWEEN '$Slong' AND '$Blong' AND `lat` BETWEEN '$Slat' AND '$Blat' AND `liking` LIKE '%{$likeArray[$newCount]}%'"
);
```

EDIT: Also, you are wide open to SQLi (SQL injection) - using PDOs and Prepared Statements will eliminate this threat. There is a good tutorial on using PHP PDO [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/214733-introduction-to-pdo/).